# better_player cant change audio track, but can change quality

Tags: flutter

I use better_player package (because of DRM and audio track select)

I want to change audio track of an .mpd (from Azure Media Services) and when select an Audio Track in RadioListTile and set it with `controller.setAudioTrack(value)` it still using the first audio track.

I can change the quality using the same procedure and it works fine.

Tried with hardcoded value aswell, but not working. How to change audio track of .mpd from Azure Media Services in flutter.